# Name of an addressing mode in x86 32b (AT&T style)

Tags: assembly, x86

I noticed in some code the following access mode I am not familiar with, and wondered if it has a name:

```
.data     
      .foo quad 0         
.text   
      ...   
      movl %edx, foo +4
```

It is quite obvious what it does or is supposed to do, but doesn't fit the syntax of addressing modes I'm used to (immediate, direct, indexed, or indirect(displacement from base as in -4(foo)) addressing).

Does it have a name? Are there restrictions on its displacement (or base) term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be absolute addressing. The address `foo+4` is known at link time, and can therefore be encoded directly into the instruction.

For example, this:

```
.text 
movl %edx, foo+4

foo:
```

yields the following `objdump` output:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   89 14 25 0b 00 00 00    mov    %edx,0xb

0000000000000007 <foo>:
```

As you can see, the address `0x0000000B` was encoded into the instruction, which equals the address of `foo` (7) plus 4.